# Sed command not working through SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, sed

Consider the following command:

```
ssh MACHINE sed -i 's#\[ "\$JBOSS_MODE" = "standalone" \]#\[ "\$JBOSS_MODE" = "sim_standalone" \]#' /tmp/sim-wildfly
```

When I run this command from the command line, I get this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unterminated `s' command
```

However, when I SSH into that particular machine first, and then run the `sed` part of the command, it works fine:

```
> ssh MACHINE
> sed -i 's#\[ "\$JBOSS_MODE" = "standalone" \]#\[ "\$JBOSS_MODE" = "sim_standalone" \]#' /tmp/sim-wildfly
```

Any idea why this would happen?

EDIT: I believe it has something to do with how I'm escaping characters, because I just tried simple test replacement with no escaped characters and it worked fine. I tried double-escaping, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ssh` with here-doc to avoid crazy escaping:

```
ssh -t -t MACHINE <<'EOF'
sed -i 's#\[ "\$JBOSS_MODE" = "standalone" \]#\[ "\$JBOSS_MODE" = "sim_standalone" \]#' /tmp/sim-wildfly
exit
EOF
```

Comment: It turned out to be the spaces, but that is a good suggestion! I'll try that.

Comment: It works, but I get this message: `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` Is there any way to get rid of that?

Comment: Ah you needed one `exit`  in the end. See updated answer.